# IHTMLElementCollection´s length changes during loop

Tags: c#, browser, mshtml

I have this code which loops over an element's nodes:

```
public static IEnumerable<IHTMLDOMNode> AllElements(this IHTMLDOMNode node)
{
    if (node.IsHTMLElement())
    {
        IHTMLElement element = (IHTMLElement)node;
        IHTMLElementCollection collection = element.all;
        int length = collection.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            IHTMLDOMNode item = collection.item(i);
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that sometimes, the collection's length will change during the looping. I placed a breakpoint at `yield return item;` that would break whenever `item` is null, and noticed when it stopped (and therefore `item` was `null`) that my `length` variable was 815,  `collection.length` was 814 and `i` was 814 so it was trying to get an item outside the range.

I know I could probably put `collection.length` inside the loop but I'm afraid this might not solve the root of the problem. Is this supposed to be possible? Is it possible for a script in the page to run at the same time my loop is running which would be the script that is removing an element inside? Or what else could be causing the collection's length to change?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a separate thread which is modifying the collection?  Or are you changing it after you   retrieve the original enumerator?  If you do something like this:

```
var all = node.AllElements();
node.removeChild(child);
all.moveNext();
```

You will encounter problems.

Comment: There is no separate thread. This is a single thread application.

Answer (score 0):

The data is live, and can be garbage-collected in the middle of the loop.  Calling GC.KeepAlive on the data *after* the loop should allow it to remain available.